# How can I select the div id using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, jquery-ui, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Working with **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**. Is there any way to select the div id instead of select id in Selenium WebDriver?

I am using this HTML:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 410.8px; left: 998.9px; z-index: 1; display: block;">
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "div id instead of select id" means?

Comment: @ t0mppa please see the attached HTML usually if element is in the form of select i will select the element through ID but here it is div.. I don't how to target that ID..

Comment: If i understand correctly....you wanted to retrieve Div element using id, then u can use the same findElement(By.id("id here") method. it works for any HTML tag irrespectively.

Comment: Exactly what @Anuragh27crony said, id's are unique within the page by HTML standards and finding an element by id doesn't hold prejudice against divs (or any other types of elements). Thus it's always the best option for locating whatever element you're looking for, if they happen to have an id attribute.

Comment: Please give me example to understand more. how to retrieve id and implantation in Selenium Web Driver..

Answer (score 3):

You can found documentation (with java example) on http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/.

In particular, the methlod you are looking for is

```
WebDriver.findElement(By)
```

Sample code is

```
WebDriver driver = new xxxDriver();
driver.get(" ... ");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
element. ... // do whatever you want with the DIV block
```

Comment: By id worked best in my case as I managed to capture an element higher on the html structure. I then cleared it using Python commands (replace, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In webdriver, you can locate elements using various ways, like xpath, css, id or class of element. Your element can be identified in any of the following ways:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div")); //by id
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']")); //by xpath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ui-datepicker-div')]")); //another xpath
```

So on and so forth. The point is these locator will work on html elements, irrespective of what they are (select, div, input etc.).